# How to remove the tool tip in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I am still working on my app and I have a question about the UISearchBar.[image]
Here is my question: How can I get rid of this "Select|Select All| Paste" tool tip appearing in the UISearchBar? 
Can any one help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it only for `UISeacrhBar` then:

```
-(void)setGestures
{
    for (id obj in searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *textF = (UITextField *)obj;
            textF.gestureRecognizers = nil;
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeSearchBarFirstResponder:)];
            textF.gestureRecognizers = @[tapGesture];
        }
    }
}

-(void)makeSearchBarFirstResponder:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [sender.view becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

And Call `[self setGestures]` method in

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self setGestures];
}
-(BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
   [self setGestures];
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 7, you can subclass UISearchBar and override this method like this:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
    }];
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

This will immediately hide the menu controller and doesn't require to parse UISearchBar subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to return **NO** for all the specific methods the menu controller performs.

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if (action == @selector(defineSelection:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(translateSelection:))
    {
        return NO; 
    }
    else if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tips. I'd like to try this. How do I hook it up to the searchBar? Just copy it in the app code? Sorry for a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

may be this code work for you..

first add notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didShowMenu:) name:UIMenuControllerDidShowMenuNotification object:nil];
```

then implement notification method in which you can hide menu

```
-(void)didShowMenu:(NSNotification*) notification{
UIMenuController *menuCon = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[menuCon setMenuVisible:FALSE];
```

}

Comment: Correct for only this situation because he has only searchBar, no textFields, textView, webView here ... Because it will hide the menu for all controls. And one more think it hides after shown the menuController.... it blinks